# User defined function returning wrong count in c++

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write program to calculate and display the number of primes in the first 50 “chiliads”. There must be 2 user defined functions "isPrime" and "primeCount". It seems like the "primeCount" is appending 4469969 to every count. It isn't doing that when I paste it into the main function.

```
int main (){
     long x = 1;
     long y = 1000;
     char reply;   

     cout << "Start   End    Number of Primes" << endl;

    while (y <= 50000)
    {
      cout << x << " " << y << " ";
      cout << primeCount(x, y) << endl;
      x = 1000 + x;
      y = 1000 + y;          
     }

    //exits the program                     
    cout << "Enter q to quit... ";
    cin >> reply;
    return 0;
}// End main function
bool isPrime(long n)
{
 long i = 2;

 if (n == 1)
    return false;
 if (n == 2) 
       return true;
 if (n == 3)
       return true;
 if ((n % 2) == 0)
        return false;
 if ((n % 3) == 0)
        return false;

 while (i < n) 
 {
     if (n % i == 0 )
     {
        return false;
     }
     else 
     {
          i++;
     }      
 }
return true;
}
long primeCount (long x, long y)
{
  long count = 0;
  while (x < y)
  {
      if (isPrime(x) == 1)
      {
         count++;
      }
  x++;  
  }
cout << count;
}
```

Comment: Your function `primeCount()` doesn't return anything, and it has a `cout` statement in it. Also, your `isPrime()` returns a `bool`, yet you compare this value to `1`.

Comment: Don't you want to return `count` in `primeCount` rather than output the value?

Comment: You are using cout<<primeCount(x,y)<<endl; but it doesn't return the true primeCount value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not returning a value from "primeCount" you were printing it.

I cleaned up the code as follows, along with some optimizations (we prove that the candidate is odd, so we don't need to check even divisors, and we only check for the value of 2 when we already know the number is even, saving us 1 extra test per odd number).

```
#include <iostream>

// prototypes for functions we implement after we use them.
long primeCount(long x, long y);
bool isPrime(long n);

int main (){
    long x = 1;
    long y = 1000;

    std::cout << "Start   End    Number of Primes" << std::endl;

    while (y <= 50000)
    {
        std::cout << x << " " << y << " ";
        std::cout << primeCount(x, y) << std::endl;
        x += 1000;
        y += 1000;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(long n)
{
    if((n & 1) == 0) // even
       return (n == 2);
    if(n == 1)
        return false;
    for (long i = 3; i < n / 2; i += 2)
    {
        if ((n % i) == 0 )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

long primeCount(long x, long y)
{
    long count = 0;
    while (x < y)
    {
        if (isPrime(x))
            count++;
        ++x;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know 1 is not a prime number.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Re-ordered and corrected -- no point checking 1 every time since it'll be invalid for half the numbers it has to check :)